# libpng writing 16bit RGB png incorrectly, shifting all image to left

Tags: c++, c, png, libpng

I am trying to write 16bit RGB image using libpng in c++.
I have done the following

```
 .....
 FILE* fp = fopen(path, "wb");
 png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
 info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
 png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

 png_set_IHDR( png_ptr,
  info_ptr,
  width,
  height,
  16,
  PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB,
  PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
  PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE,
  PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);

  png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
  png_set_swap(png_ptr);
  bytep row = (png_bytep)malloc(6 * width * sizeof(png_byte));
  for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
   for(int x = 0; x <width; x++){
      set_rgb(&(row[x * 3]), array[y]);
   }
     png_write_row(png_ptr, row);
  }
  .....
```

where array is congaing float values of RGB, and `set_rgb()` I do

```
void set_normal_rgb(png_byte* ptr, and array...) {

  ptr[0] = array[0];
  ptr[1] = array[1];
  ptr[2] = array[2];
}
```

However, image produce would look something like this

[image produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPLdN.png)
Where all the correct image are squashed to the left half, and right half is just some random noise. I do know that I am not assigning pixels correctly, and that each pixels needs to be 6 bytes. Tried reading up the API but still not clear what the correct way is to assign individual pixels in 16 bits RGB image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimum, compilable example

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the problem is obvious. You only have half an image, but in your code you have `6 * width * sizeof(png_byte)` and `&(row[x * 3]`. 3 is half of 6, so that's why you get only half an image. Have you tried `x * 6`? And obviously you need to change `set_rgb` to copy six bytes instead of three.

Comment: Change the type of `row` to `uint16_t*` instead of `bytep`. In C++: `uint16_t *row = new uint16_t[3*width];` You will need to cast it back to a `bytep` when you pass it to `png_write_row`, though.

Comment: @john changing it to 6 would result in completely random image where entire image is a noise

Comment: @nEWBIEpROGRAMMER But at least it would be the right size! Obviously the next thing to do is to work out how to copy the bytes. Have you tried botje's suggestion? One way of another you need to copy six bytes not three.